# Installing packages in Python3.4 by easy_install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, easy-install

I am having Anaconda3 and Python3.4. But when i run `easy_install`, packges get installed in `Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` and I want to do it for `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages`. How to do it?

Comment: Anaconda has it's own python installation. You need to install python separately and run pip or easy_install from that directory

Comment: I run C:\Python34\Scripts > easy_install gensim... but its not working. It shows blank

Comment: try to use pip from the same directory, otherwise remove Anaconda and repeat with bare python

Comment: yeah it worked :) @minitoto

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Command prompt
2. Go to Python34/Scripts

> cd C://Python34//Scripts

3. Install your packages using pip

> pip install yourpackegeName